# clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear on iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13

Starting iOS 13 `viewWillAppear` is not longer called when controller is using the new presentation style and is dismissed. This means `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` on `UITableViewController` does not work anymore. Does one have to clear the selection manually somehow or is there any other option out there?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568967/detecting-sheet-was-dismissed-on-ios-13

Comment: You are totally right, i did correct my question.
I guess the answer of the mentioned question will work but still one have to clear the selection manually. Thank you for enlightening me.