# How to run code when view controller in iOS is dismissed by swiping down?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I have a view controller that I present in my iOS app using Swift and Xcode that is able to be dismissed by swiping down on it. I need to implement code that executes when the user swipes down on the view controller to dismiss it. I suspect there is a callback function that is called when that happens. Can anyone tell me if that's so and what the callback function is?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568967/detecting-sheet-was-dismissed-on-ios-13/56569048#56569048

Comment: Yes. I think that's what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Without too much information this is how I would set it up:

My views would be on a Navigation controller

On the view I want to dismiss with down swipe I would use a Gesture recognizer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
   view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

// Handle swipe down detected
@objc func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // Do whatever you want before you leave

    // Pop back a view
    if let nav = navigationController {
       nav.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```