# Firebase Screen name issue with modal views in iOS 13 and above

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics, modalviewcontroller

In our app we are tracking screen views manually by adding relevant codes in `viewWillAppear` functions. With iOS 13, with the **non fullscreen modals**, the `viewWillAppear` of the parent screen won't get called when the modal is dismissed and hence wrong screen names are reported there after, for events originating from the parent screen.

I have checked the [Detecting sheet was dismissed on iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568967/detecting-sheet-was-dismissed-on-ios-13) , but the solution to implement  `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` helps when you manually swipes down.

I then turned off manual tracking and turned on Automatic tracking and surprisingly the screen classes are determined right. Question is how Firebase is figuring that out?

Of-course I can't use auto tracking as we need custom screen names.
I believe this could be a generic issue for whoever using manual screen name tracking and have non full screen modals. Just wanted to check what's the best way to solve this.
Couple of ideas I had was

1. Make all modals full screen. Not nice for our app
2. Implement extra delegates in those modals to let the parent know its dismissed. Not sure its a nice way
3. Setting screen names on each event? Could that be even possible?

If there are any other nicer/ cleaner option let me know.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Comment: Not in a standard way, we decided to supply our own screen names as custom parameters to each relevant events